# Can't use columnwidth excel property

Tags: c#, excel, properties

I'm trying to set the width of one or a few cells in Excel.

This is my code

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xla = new    
      Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
Workbook wb = xla.Workbooks.Add(XlSheetType.xlWorksheet);
Worksheet ws = (Worksheet)xla.ActiveSheet;
```

i know if i going to change entire columns width

```
ws.Columns.ColumnWidth = 30;
ws.Cells.ColumnWidth = 30;
```

but when i try to change spesific columns with this following code

```
ws.Columns[5].ColumnWidth = 30; 
*//or* 
ws.Cells [5, 5].ColumnWidth = 30;
**//or* 
ws.Columns["E:E"].ColumnWidth = 30;
```

property `ColumnWidth` can't be used
in list after i type colums[5] then dot just appear 'Equals, GetHahCode, Gettype, ToString'
when i try to manually type it
**it's give error 'No Overload for method 'this' takes '1' argument'**

i used visual studio 2010 and framework 4.0
I wonder what I'm missing ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably using target framework to be .Net framework 3.5 or lower. Change it to .Net Framework 4.0 and it will work fine. This dynamic property exists only in Framework 4.0. To change framework right click on the project on the solution explorer. Click on properties and set the value for target framework to .NET framework 4.0 using the drop down. This should definitely work. Try and let me know if it doesn't work for you.

Comment: you are right i use net framework 3.5 but it's weird it's not available net framework 4.0 in drop down...the highest is framework 3.5...i already check it with windwos exploler & cmd, net framework 4.0 already installed in my system

Comment: oh yeah forgot to write 'i used visual C# 2008' express edition

Comment: after searhing, i found if vs 2008 stuck with framework 3.5...so i guess i will move to visual studio 2010

Comment: Yup.. move to VS 2010 or VS 2012.. and it will work absolutely fine. Happy to help you..

Comment: i still get same error, i can't use .columnWidth property after i type spesifict column [5] like in vs2008...any idea?

Comment: i told you may have to move to vs2010 or higher to use this property.

Comment: that i try in vs2010...i mean after i upgrading to vs2010, i'm still can't use column[5].columnWidth property like in vs2008....if just ws.column.columnWIdth in vs2008 able to do it too

Comment: i finally able to set property column (width, bold,etc) with this code 'column.get_Range("A!", "A3").columnWidth = 30'

Comment: Great. good to see that u didnt give up on it and finally got it work your way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use MS-Office Macros to get the desired code snippets.

For example i run a simple Macro, then changed the width of the favorite column and at last stopped the macro to view the VB code of this operation.

This is very useful when you are going to do a very complicated task in Ms-Office products.

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    Columns("J:J").ColumnWidth = 22.5
End Sub
```

The above macro is used to set the width of the column J

Answer (score 0):

@Katik: i am able to change the column width using just this

`ws.Columns[5].ColumnWidth = 17.57;`

May be we will be able to help if you let us know what kind of error or what kind of behavioral change do you see when you use the above statement.

Comment: i adding more describe, please check my post